# Extract the text from String inside BizTalk orchestration

Tags: c#, biztalk

I have to extract a message in a string. Below is the string which I have

```
An error occurred while processing the message, refer to the details section for more information 
Message ID: {AA607FE1}
Instance ID: {EE3E9721}
Error Description:The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.
The creation of the order failed is invalid.
```

The Output Should be :

```
Error Description:The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.
The creation of the order failed  is invalid.
```

Comment: does the string have line breaks in between like `Message ID: {AA607FE1} \r\n
Instance ID: {EE3E9721} \r\n`

Comment: This is how it is  , Message ID: {AA607FE1}\n Instance ID: {EE3E9721}\n